# How can I copy a file from my machine to another machine from command line?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, upload

Something like

```
cp \\target_machine local_file.txt c:\dest_file.txt
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have appropriate permissions, you can do it like this:

```
copy local_file.txt \\target_machine\c$\dest_file.txt
```

Use "c$" to reference C drive on the remote machine.

Comment: How do you include a username and password to authenticate if you don't have appropriate permissions?

Comment: Searching around suggests `net use` to provide the authentication to the share before copying (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854026). Not sure if that works with the c$ notation above though, you'd have to try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

It's like this:

`copy c:\local_path\local_file.txt \\target_machine\destination_path\destination_file.txt`

If you have `\\target_machine\destination_path\` mapped to a network drive, say, `Z:`
then the command becomes

`copy c:\local_path\local_file.txt Z:\destination_file.txt`

Comment: when I try the first option (without the c$ stuff) I get "The system cannot find the path specified" or "The network name cannot be found", depending on one or two backslashes before machine name.

Comment: Hmm, there was an error in Markdownformatting which showed only single backslash instead of 2. If you're getting `The network name cannot be found` then it's a network problem, either you don't have permissions or the firewall is blocking your requests

Comment: I tried both one and two backslashes, and got the different error messages depending on which I used. "Network name cannot be found" was with two backslashes. Interesting. That works with your network setup? It didn't work with either our server or other clients...

Comment: @Ash single backslash indicates you are accessing the current drive, hence you got the `system cannot find path specified error`. Double backslash is used for accessing network shares with UNC naming scheme. Yes, this works on my network, I have couple of scripts where I make use of this ( scripts are to export data, compress them and move them to NAS). I suspect permissions problems. Are the machines you want to copy on different domains/workgroups ?

Comment: On Windows machines/networks, a share such as `c$` must be used.